# pattern replacement in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

In the below example, i want to replace the string "lastName:JordanlastName:Jordan" with "lastName:Jordan" i.e, when the pattern repeats i want to stop. i want to do this for every record. How to do this in R?

lastName:Portnoy

lastName:JordanlastName:JordanlastName:Jordan

lastName:JordanlastName:JordanlastName:Jordan

lastName:CliffordlastName:CliffordlastName:Clifford

lastName:WalkerlastName:Walker

lastName:Portnoy

Comment: How do you known that `"lastName:JordanlastName:Jordan"`is not your pattern, but `"lastName:Jordan"` is? From the fact that you have only one semicolon (`":"`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read in the example data:
x <- unname(unlist(c(read.table(text="lastName:Portnoy
lastName:JordanlastName:JordanlastName:Jordan
lastName:JordanlastName:JordanlastName:Jordan
lastName:CliffordlastName:CliffordlastName:Clifford
lastName:WalkerlastName:Walker
lastName:Portnoy", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))))
# Delete everything after the first occurrence of the pattern:
sub('(?<=[a-z])lastName[A-Za-z:]+', '', x, perl=TRUE)

[1] "lastName:Portnoy"  "lastName:Jordan"   "lastName:Jordan"  
[4] "lastName:Clifford" "lastName:Walker"   "lastName:Portnoy"
```

This replaces every occurrence of "lastName" and the following characters and colons with nothing ('') **if and only if** there was a letter before it.

### Details

`sub()` has three mandatory arguments: `pattern`, `replacement`, and `x`. I've also used the optional `perl=TRUE` argument because the `pattern` I used is a Perl-style regular expression. I've told `sub()` to look in the character vector `x` for the pattern `'(?<=[a-z])lastName[A-Za-z:]+'` and replace it with `''`, or nothing (equivalent to deleting those characters). The `(?<=[a-z])` part of the pattern is called a "look-behind assertion." That means the pattern matches `'lastName[A-Za-z:]+'` if and only if it finds a letter immediately preceding that pattern. `'lastName[A-Za-z:]+'` looks for the exact characters "lastName" followed immediately by one or more characters in the set of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and the colon character. It matches everything until it finds a character that is not in that set.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. can you explain how this works sub('(?<=[a-z])lastName[A-Za-z:]+', '', x, perl=TRUE)

Comment: I've added some explanatory details that I hope clears this up. If you find yourself dealing with issues sort of like this often, I'd recommend reading more broadly on regular expressions in R, perhaps starting [here](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html). I'm glad this worked for you; since it solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer, which can help others searching Stack Overflow with a similar problem.